# (Android Studio) My Tic-Tac-Toe game is not showing the winner correctly

Tags: java, android

I am a beginner to Android. I have created a simple Tic-Tac-Toe game. It has a grid and a status bar that shows whose turn it is and who has won. The problem is that most of the times it shows the wrong winner. Only in a few situations it shows the winner correctly. In some situations the status bar even disappears. I have tried changing the String (winner) but it did not worked out.
Here is my MainActivity.java:

```
package com.jashanubhi.tictactoeme;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int activePlayer = 0;
    boolean gameActive = true;
    int[] gameState = {2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2};
    int[][] winningPositions = {{0,1,2}, {3,4,5}, {6,7,8},
                                {0,4,8}, {2,4,6},
                                {0,3,6}, {1,4,7}, {2,5,8}};

    public void playerTap(View view) {

        ImageView img;
        img = (ImageView) view;
        int tappedImage;
        tappedImage = Integer.parseInt(img.getTag().toString());
        if(!gameActive){
            gameReset(view);
        }
        if(gameActive) {
            if (gameState[tappedImage] == 2) {
                gameState[tappedImage] = activePlayer;
                img.setTranslationY(-1000f);
                if (activePlayer == 0) {
                    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.x);
                    activePlayer = 1;
                    TextView status;
                    status = findViewById(R.id.status);
                    status.setText("O's Turn - Tap to Play");
                } else {
                    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.o);
                    activePlayer = 0;
                    TextView status;
                    status = findViewById(R.id.status);
                    status.setText("X's Turn - Tap to Play");
                }
                img.animate().translationYBy(1000f).setDuration(300);
            }
        }
        gameActive = true;
            for (int[] winningPosition : winningPositions) {
                if (gameState[winningPosition[0]] == gameState[winningPosition[1]] && gameState[winningPosition[1]] == gameState[winningPosition[2]]
                        && gameState[winningPosition[0]] != 2) {
                    String winner = null;
                    if (winningPosition[0] == 0) {
                        winner = "X has won";
                    }
                    if (winningPosition[0] == 1) {
                        winner = "O has won";
                    }
                    TextView status = findViewById(R.id.status);
                    status.setText(winner);
                    gameActive = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
    }

    public void gameReset(View view){
        activePlayer = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < gameState.length; i++){
            gameState[i] = 2;
        }
        ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView0)).setImageResource(0);
        ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1)).setImageResource(0);
        ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2)).setImageResource(0);
        ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView3)).setImageResource(0);
        ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView4)).setImageResource(0);
        ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView5)).setImageResource(0);
        ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView6)).setImageResource(0);
        ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView7)).setImageResource(0);
        ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView8)).setImageResource(0);
        TextView status = findViewById(R.id.status);
        status.setText("X's Turn - Tap to Play");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="@string/title"
        android:textSize="38dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="398dp"
        android:layout_height="398dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/grid" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/status"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="X's Turn - Tap to Play"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="398dp"
        android:layout_height="398dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView0"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="playerTap"
                android:padding="23sp"
                android:tag="0" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="playerTap"
                android:padding="23sp"
                android:tag="1" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="playerTap"
                android:padding="23sp"
                android:tag="2" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="playerTap"
                android:padding="23sp"
                android:tag="3" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="playerTap"
                android:padding="23sp"
                android:tag="4" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView5"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="playerTap"
                android:padding="23sp"
                android:tag="5" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView6"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="playerTap"
                android:padding="23sp"
                android:tag="6" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView7"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="playerTap"
                android:padding="23sp"
                android:tag="7" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView8"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="playerTap"
                android:padding="23sp"
                android:tag="8" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: What do you mean? I have tried changing the String (winner)

Comment: Sometimes when the winner is O, the status bar shows that the winner is X.In only a few situations it shows that the winner is O. When X wins, very rarely it shows that O has won, but most of the times it shows that X has won. So i tried swapping their positions in their respective if statements by changing the String winner (declared in code).But that did not worked out.

Comment: So check your rules of game

Comment: I have checked the array for the positions to win `winningPositions`. It is correct.

Comment: I think your problem is in winningPositions which has 8 rows and 3 columns. So winningPosition get 0 to 7 meanwhile you want it to get just 0 to 2.

Comment: You can define one dimension array which has 9 places, if for example places 0 and 1 and 2 is X show X is won. If they are O so O is won. I think it is easier in compare of using two dimensional array.

Comment: By using a single dimensional array we would not be able check whether X or O are present in 3 positions of the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For implementing Tic-Tac-Toe game in Java try this code:

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.codinginflow.tictactoe.MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_p1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Player 1: 0"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_p2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/text_view_p1"
            android:text="Player 2: 0"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_reset"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="33dp"
            android:text="reset" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_00"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="60sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_01"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="60sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_02"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="60sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_10"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="60sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_11"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="60sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_12"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="60sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_20"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="60sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_21"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="60sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_22"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="60sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private Button[][] buttons = new Button[3][3];

    private boolean player1Turn = true;

    private int roundCount;

    private int player1Points;
    private int player2Points;

    private TextView textViewPlayer1;
    private TextView textViewPlayer2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textViewPlayer1 = findViewById(R.id.text_view_p1);
        textViewPlayer2 = findViewById(R.id.text_view_p2);

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                String buttonID = "button_" + i + j;
                int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(buttonID, "id", getPackageName());
                buttons[i][j] = findViewById(resID);
                buttons[i][j].setOnClickListener(this);
            }
        }

        Button buttonReset = findViewById(R.id.button_reset);
        buttonReset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                resetGame();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (!((Button) v).getText().toString().equals("")) {
            return;
        }

        if (player1Turn) {
            ((Button) v).setText("X");
        } else {
            ((Button) v).setText("O");
        }

        roundCount++;

        if (checkForWin()) {
            if (player1Turn) {
                player1Wins();
            } else {
                player2Wins();
            }
        } else if (roundCount == 9) {
            draw();
        } else {
            player1Turn = !player1Turn;
        }

    }

    private boolean checkForWin() {
        String[][] field = new String[3][3];

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                field[i][j] = buttons[i][j].getText().toString();
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            if (field[i][0].equals(field[i][1])
                    && field[i][0].equals(field[i][2])
                    && !field[i][0].equals("")) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            if (field[0][i].equals(field[1][i])
                    && field[0][i].equals(field[2][i])
                    && !field[0][i].equals("")) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        if (field[0][0].equals(field[1][1])
                && field[0][0].equals(field[2][2])
                && !field[0][0].equals("")) {
            return true;
        }

        if (field[0][2].equals(field[1][1])
                && field[0][2].equals(field[2][0])
                && !field[0][2].equals("")) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    private void player1Wins() {
        player1Points++;
        Toast.makeText(this, "Player 1 wins!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        updatePointsText();
        resetBoard();
    }

    private void player2Wins() {
        player2Points++;
        Toast.makeText(this, "Player 2 wins!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        updatePointsText();
        resetBoard();
    }

    private void draw() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Draw!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        resetBoard();
    }

    private void updatePointsText() {
        textViewPlayer1.setText("Player 1: " + player1Points);
        textViewPlayer2.setText("Player 2: " + player2Points);
    }

    private void resetBoard() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                buttons[i][j].setText("");
            }
        }

        roundCount = 0;
        player1Turn = true;
    }

    private void resetGame() {
        player1Points = 0;
        player2Points = 0;
        updatePointsText();
        resetBoard();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        outState.putInt("roundCount", roundCount);
        outState.putInt("player1Points", player1Points);
        outState.putInt("player2Points", player2Points);
        outState.putBoolean("player1Turn", player1Turn);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        roundCount = savedInstanceState.getInt("roundCount");
        player1Points = savedInstanceState.getInt("player1Points");
        player2Points = savedInstanceState.getInt("player2Points");
        player1Turn = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("player1Turn");
    }
}
```

See here for more details: https://codinginflow.com/tutorials/android/tic-tac-toe/