# Not Expected Output in Android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to build a simple tic tac toe game in Android Studio and want to display the O's and X's whenever the user clicks on the grid element but it isn't showing the expected output and whenever i tried to click on the grid in the tic tac toe then it shows the app not responding error.

This is my onTap func which i have added in all the grid elements in the xml file:

```
public void onTap(View view) {
     final ImageView[] box = new ImageView[9];
     for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
          box[i] = findViewById(R.id.imageView + i);
         final int k = i;
         box[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View view) {
                 box[k].setImageResource(R.drawable.o);
             }
         });
    }

 }
```

Comment: You need to post the full logcat output so we can see what the exception is.

Comment: Why does `i` go from 1 to 9 when your `box` array only has indices that go from 0 to 8?

Comment: Are you sure the error is "application not responding" and not "application has stopped working"?

Comment: yes it shows stopped working

Comment: the range of i doesn't make the output different

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60968622/12478830

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things wrong here. First:

```
 final ImageView[] box = new ImageView[9];
 for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
```

In Java array indices start with 0, and an array with 9 item has indices 0 through 8. Change the loop to:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
```

The next problem is here:

```
 box[i] = findViewById(R.id.imageView + i);
```

View IDs are not consecutive numbers. You cannot just add `i` to an existing view ID and hope that the result a valid ID.

Assuming your views have IDs `R.id.imageView1`-`R.id.imageView9`, you could change the code that creates the `box` array to:

```
 ImageView[] box = {
     findViewById(R.id.imageView1), 
     findViewById(R.id.imageView2),
     ...
     findViewById(R.id.imageView9)
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a `String` for your ID and use the `findViewById()` like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
   String boxID = "imageView"+ i;
   int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(boxID, "id", getPackageName());
   box[i] = findViewById(resID);
   box[i].setOnClickListener(this);
}
```